# getch() showing prototype error

Tags: c++

I have just started learning c++ and I want the programme to stay open after the result is displayed. So I used getch(); and c++ is showing that it should have a prototype. What does it mean? and how do I resolve this>

Comment: Show the exact error.

Comment: Are you sure it's `c++` and not `c`?

Comment: The point Eugene was trying to make is that `getch` is not used in C++, it is only used in C (and then only in old-school Windows programming). In C++, you would use `std::cin`. If your book is purporting to teach you C++, but talks about `getch`, then it is not a good book. [Get a better one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @ivanRubinson getch() should have a prototype is the exact error

Comment: So how do I make the programme stay? @codyGray

Comment: OP wants just to _pause_ the screen. Look at my answer

Comment: In Visual Studio, start the program with Ctrl+F5. It will remain on the screen until you close it. It only closes automatically when you have the debugger attached. If you're not debugging it, use Ctrl+F5. Or, you can include `<cstdio>` and use `std::getchar` (but beware that is not an ideal solution, because if there are already characters buffered, it will just consume them and continue on).

Comment: If it is C++, You can just use cin.ignore() :)

Answer (score 3):

it means one of the followings:

1. you are programming under DOS and forgot to include conio.h (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h). Possibly you copied a source from an older textbook, since conio.h is a very old concept. What sources do you use for learning? I'd recommend one from: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
2. You are programming under Linux and you forgot to include curses.h (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch)

Comment: You forgot Windows.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't think any (self respecting) windows compiler ships with conio.h. It's an old Turbo C header by Borland if I remember correctly.

Comment: conio.h is still deliverd with my Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: It is delivered with my "Fancy" Visual studio 15 Preview.

Comment: Also, It is delivered to some POSIX machines.

Comment: The conio header included with modern Windows compilers is very different than the conio header included with ancient Borland DOS-based compilers. They just have the same name, and both deal with console I/O. The main thing they have in common is that they should no longer be used, *certainly* not in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Include:

1) `<conio.h>` on Windows.

2) `<curses.h>` on UNIX

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you only want to **PAUSE** your console application on the screen. Use this`#include <stdio.h>` and try `getchar();` instead of `getch();` or simply `system("pause");` or `cin.ignore()` will do the job for you.

Also, "*Start without Debugging*" using Ctrl-F5 will allow you to *Press Any Key To Continue* at the end of your program. This way it won't close until you press some key and the console will pause on the display screen.

Comment: You did not add the "C++" solution: `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: @MatthewRoh here you go :)

Comment: Nice! :) Now It matches the C++ tag.

Comment: @Math You mean what I mentioned could not have worked :)?

Comment: No, but with `cin.ignore()`, you do not have to include `stdio.h` (or, do I have to say, `cstdio`?)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows then `getch` is a function from the Windows-only [`<conio.h>` library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h). You need to include it (`#include <conio.h>`).
It's possible only on Windows.

Also, `getch()` is deprecated.
Use `_getch()` instead.

---

If you're on GNU+Linux, then `getch` is a function from the [`<curses.h>` library](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch). You need to include it (`#include <curses.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

The objective as I understand is :

> I want programme to stay open after the result is displayed

Why not do it the typical `c++` way?

```
#include<iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char ch;
std::cout<<"Enter any character : ";
std::cin.get(ch);  // For testing enter a string at this step say "String"

/* The input to cin is line-buffered, so after reading 'S' to ch,
 * the remaining "tring" is still in the buffer.
 */

std::cout<<"Entered character : "<<ch<<"\n";
while(std::cin.get()!='\n')
;; 
/* cin.get() is an overloaded function in the istream class.
 * If no arguments are passed to 'get()' this function reads single next character
 * In essence, we wait for the cin.get() to clear the buffer that is
 * read all characters including '\n'
 */

std::cout<<"Press any key to continue..\n";
std::cin.get();
/* Since we have already cleared the buffer using the loop
 * 'get()' expects us to enter a character this time
 */

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `cin.ignore()`?

Comment: @MatthewRoh : Well, I haven't used that method before..After reading your comments from the other answer, I'm currently reading the manual for that. Will update in a moment.

Comment: @MatthewRoh : My first impression is that using cin.ignore() is a luxury here.. I may finish the job with more easily understood `while()` loop